# woocommerce - make order notes required

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

is it posible to make woo 'order_comments' field required - and show message If the field is not filled

I have tried the following code but I can not get it to work.

```html
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');
 
function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['my_field_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Hope there is someone who can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the action from '`woocommerce_checkout_process`' to '`woocommerce_after_checkout_validation`'.

```
 add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

  function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
            // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
            if ( ! $_POST['order_comments'] )
                wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter something into this new shiny field.' ), 'error' );
        }
```

Comment: I have changed the field name from 'my_field_name' to 'order_comments'. Try this.

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in "functions.php" file of an active child theme.

```
// Make order notes required
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wc_override_checkout_fields' );
function wc_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
     return $fields;
}
```

Reference https://gist.github.com/MindyPostoff/cbf34de936445972737f